# Spring Boot Gradle Driver for test database [h2] is not available

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-kotlin

I am using H2 database with Spring Boot project. I have runtime dependency on h2 in build.gradle.kts file, but it is not able to find the driver.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [H2] is not available
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.getConfigurer(EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.java:57) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:132) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.java:121) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.datarestdemo.DataRestDemoApplication.dataSource(DataRestDemoApplication.kt:24) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.datarestdemo.DataRestDemoApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e09cdea.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.datarestdemo.DataRestDemoApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e09cdea$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1a09d5e.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.datarestdemo.DataRestDemoApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e09cdea.dataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 217 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.getInstance(H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:51) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.getConfigurer(EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 230 common frames omitted
```

This is how I added the runtime dependency

`runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")`

and this is plugin configuration

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Running from command line with `gradle bootRun` command works fine

Comment: running main method within IntelliJ is causing problem

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause ? I spent hours on this and your comment of using gradle bootRun worked. thanks

Comment: I think gradle bootRun trigger bootJar task which generates a fat jar containing all the dependencies that are needed at runtime as well. That is something which intellij might not be doing and may be it only looked at compile classpath.